# Can't close a window- why?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nswindow

I have an application in which a window should be opened and closed when a checkbox is clicked on or off in a separate window. I can open it, but can't close it. I define a NSWindow in the windowControllerObject and try to close the NSWindow. The relevant code is:

buttonController.h

```
@interface buttonController : NSWindowController
{
NSButton *showAnswerBox;
infoWindowController *answerWindowController;
}
- (IBAction)showAnswer:(id)sender;
@end
```

buttonController.m

```
- (IBAction) showAnswer:(id) sender
{
     if ([sender state] == NSOnState) {
         if (!answerWindowController) {
             answerWindowController = [[infoWindowController alloc] init];
             }
         [answerWindowController showWindow:self];
         }
     else {
        [answerWindowController hideWindow];
     }
}
```

infoWindowController.h:

```
@interface infoWindowController : NSWindowController {

IBOutlet NSWindow * infoWindow; 
}
- (id) init;
- (NSWindow *) window; 
- (void) hideWindow;
- (void) tsSetTitle: (NSString *) displayName;

@end
```

And in infoWindowController.m:

```
- (NSWindow *) window
{
     return infoWindow;
}

- (void) hideWindow
{
  [[self window] close];
}
```

The window opens, but it won't close. I've tried several variations, including orderOut on the infoWindowController. I'm sure I'm missing something dumb- what is it?

In IB, the only way I can even get the windows to open is if 'Open at launch' checked- shouldn't I be able to open them programmatically without that?

Comment: Done any debugging? Methods called? Variables valid?

Comment: Are you intentionally overriding the window property with your own implementation ? What happens for [infoWindow close] in your hideWindow method

Comment: Have modified your code. Please verify

Comment: Wain: Yes, I added NSLog messages to verify which methods were called. I removed them for brevity.

Comment: Warren: No, I didn't. I'll check into that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`NSWindowController` already defines a `window` property. You have effectively overridden the getter of that property by implementing your own `-window` method. The setter, though, is still the inherited version.

So, assuming you have connected the `window` outlet of the controller to the window in the NIB, the inherited setter is being called. That allows the inherited implementation of `-showWindow:` to work to show the window. But your `-window` method will return `nil` because the inherited setter does not set your `infoWindow` instance variable.

Get rid of your separate `infoWindow` property and getter. Just use the inherited `window` property and its accessors.

Comment: Ken: I've removed that stuff, and it's still not working. The problem may lay in this comment: "So, assuming you have connected the window outlet of the controller to the window in the NIB". I haven't done that. Do I need to make a window outlet in the infoWindowController interface? `IBOutlet window` How is it implemented?

Comment: Ken, I finally figured it out. I added an outlet `window` to the file owner, type NSWindow, and control dragged it to the window of interest. Thanks to you and everyone.

Comment: Usually, you set the class of the File's Owner to be your custom subclass of `NSWindowController`. Then, IB knows about the inherited `window` outlet and you can connect it. Directly telling IB that the File's Owner has a `window` outlet also works, but you probably want it to know your controller's class, anyway. That way, as you add more properties or maybe action methods, they'll automatically be available. I recommend this [blog article](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2013-04-05-windows-and-window-controllers.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you use `NSWindowController` it's better to use it's `close` method:

```
- (void) hideWindow
{
  [self close];
}
```

or just:

```
[answerWindowController close];
```

But your code is also valid, just make sure that your `[answerWindowController window]` is not nil. If you load your window from xib you should initialize your window controller with the name of this xib: `answerWindowController = [[AnswerWindowControllerClass alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"YOUR WINDOW XIB NAME"];`.

Also check that "Visible at launch" is unchecked for your window (it seems that it doesn't).